# Fastboot gets stuck on waiting for device trying to access Fairphone device on Arch linux

Tags: fastboot, usb-debugging, fairphone-3

Basically through the `fastboot` "API"  i cannot access/see the Fairphone 3+, while theandroid debug bridge is working.
Using `adb devices` lets me see the device and `adb reboot bootloader` reboots the phone.

My steps so far are:

**On Arch linux:**

- installed:  android-tools; android-udev and android-file-transfer
- setup new udev rules for the device following [this article.](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Android_Debug_Bridge)

  - `SUBSYSTEM=="usb",ATTR{idVendor}=="...", MODE="0660", GROUP="adbusers", OWNER="..."`
  - `SUBSYSTEM=="usb",ATTR{idVendor}=="...",ATTR{idProduct}=="...",SYMLINK+="android_adb", OWNER="..."`
  - `SUBSYSTEM=="usb",ATTR{idVendor}=="...",ATTR{idProduct}=="...",SYMLINK+="android_fastboot", OWNER="..."`
- tried running fastboot as root

**On Fairphone**:

- enabled Developer mode
- Get the IMEI and SerialNumber to unlock the bootloader code
- Enable OEM unlocking
- when fastbooting (through adb)

  - i select START and continue with the boot process

** Connection attempts**

- Trying both USB 2.0 and USB 3.0 ports on my laptop
- (The USB-C cable i am using is an official fp cable)

When now using `fastboot oem unlock` or any fastboot command i get stuck with `<waiting for device>`

Maybe fastboot cannot access the USb devices?
What do i have to do to actually be able to use fastboot?

Comment: What does `sudo fastboot devices` show?

Comment: *"adb reboot bootloader reboots the phone"* and *"i select START and continue with the boot process"* indicates you haven't entered fastboot mode, therefore fastboot commands can't work. enter fastboot mode with *Vol Down + Power*